# Links in .php files are not clickable

Tags: phpstorm

My question is that a normal behavior of PhpStorm to not following links when `Ctrl + Click` on them (in `.php` file)?

I don't want to highlight the link and copy to browser, want them to behave like in `.html` files, where `Ctrl + Click` works.

Here is code:

```
<?PHP

class account {
    protected $key;
    protected $account_url = "http://example.com/";
```

`"http://example.com/"` - from PhpStorm I cant see the way to open it quickly.

Comment: *"is that a normal behavior of PhpStorm"* -- considering that this URL is located in ordinary string -- Yes. PhpStorm does not check ordinary strings for URLs; it only checks more deterministic places (e.g. `@see` or `@link` tags in PHPDoc comments and stuff like that).

Comment: Thanks for reply, roger that.